# dev-c++ print out a heart symbol

Tags: c++, unicode, dev-c++

I'm trying to print out a heart symbol in dev-c++.

To print out a heart I wrote

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    char heart = 3;

    cout << "Heart = " << heart << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

However, it doesn't print out a heart on my computer. I also changed the ANSI setting to "yes".
My classmates and professor can see the heart symbol but not me :/ Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Seeing the heart is  a function of your OS terminal

Comment: I use Windows 10. Is there any solution to see the heart symbol?

Comment: `3` is the ascii code for "end of text". What heart are you talking about??

Comment: If you want to print a heart symbol on the terminal you need to print an actual unicode heart symbol (e.g. U+2764 ❤) and the terminal must be configured for unicode and use a font that has that symbol.

Comment: I just tested the code in Windows 10 and used VSCode as the IDE with mingw from msys2 as the compiler. Then changed directory to the folder with the executable and ran it and I got the heart with no changes to the code.

Comment: @Slome tell your professor that some random guy on the internet respectfully told him to explain to you how the ascii "end of text" is supposed to be displayed as a heart symbol. And during the explanation that he will be providing you he might figure out why it doesn't work on your system, even though it works on his system. If he doesn't figure it please tell him that the random guy on the internet told him - respectfully - that he needs to study the situation a bit and them come back to you with an explanation.

Comment: Is there any way to print out a heart using dev-c++? I know my code works. My professor used my code and successfully print out a heart but not on my computer.

Comment: I put a picture here:[https://ibb.co/RY66mTD](https://ibb.co/RY66mTD)

Comment: I don't think the IDE makes a difference.

Comment: I tested the executable produced it in Windows Terminal Version: 1.11.3471.0 in powershell and in cmd.exe and both showed the heart. In windows 10 20H2

Comment: Thank you! I think there's gotta be some problem with my computer or something. We use the same compiler and same code but it only works for him.

Comment: Try running your executable using cmd.exe. Make sure you set your PATH environment variable to point to your mingw binary folder if you get a popup error about a missing dll. I did that in the picture I posted.

Comment: @Slome You may want to come prepared. It is hard/expensive to obtain a copy of relevant ANSI or ISO standards, but a [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) might help. There is nothing heart-shaped on that page. If your professor shows you a table with a heart shape in position 3, tell him that another random guy on the 'net respectfully says that it is not a table of ASCII characters (whatever the table itself says). It is a chart of a particular Windows code page, and not everyone uses the same code page on Windows, and almost no one uses that code page outside of Windows.

Answer (score 6):

While the ASCII code 3 is a control character, the default US Windows code page of 437 and Western European Windows code page of 850 will print `Heart = ♥` in the cmd.exe window assuming the font selected supports it.  This is backwards compatible with the old DOS code pages that printed symbols for some control characters.  Your system may not be set to a font that supports it or it is a different code page.  Use `chcp` to check the code page, `chcp 437` to change it, and check the window's Properties page, Fonts tab.  Consolas, Courier New, and Lucida Console fonts all support the heart.

```
C:\test>type test.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char heart = 3;
    cout << "Heart = " << heart << endl;
    return 0;
}
C:\test>cl /nologo /EHsc /W4 test.cpp
test.cpp

C:\test>chcp
Active code page: 437

C:\test>test
Heart = ♥
```

Screenshot (Consolas font):

[image: Heart = ♥]

A more reliable way on Windows to output the correct character is to set the console text mode to support wide characters and output the proper Unicode character.  This still requires a font that supports the Unicode character, in this case U+2665 BLACK HEART SUIT, but won't care what code page the windows supports.

```py
#include<fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    std::wcout << L'\u2665' << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The ascii character with the code `3` is a  [Control Character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) or **non-printing character**, specifically it's the [End-of-Text character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Text_character).

These characters have special meaning and **do not** represent a written symbol i.e. they are **not meant** to be printed.

Some terminals are configured (or can be configured) to print control characters (mostly for debugging purposes). Some of these are configured to print the EoT character as `^C`, others as a heart, while others as something else like `□` or [`�`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760943/character-code-of-unknown-character-character-e-g-square-or-question-mark-romb). Consult your terminal documentation to see if it can be made to print as you want.

**But** control characters should not be used to print symbols and should not be expected to print symbols.

If you want to print a heart symbol on the terminal you need to print an actual unicode heart symbol (e.g. U+2764 ❤) and the terminal must be configured for unicode and use a font that has that symbol.

Comment: Yeah. I just think it's weird when my professor used my code on his computer it works but not on my computer. Also he wants me to print out a heart using 3

Comment: @Slome point him to this post and to [my previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70858305/dev-c-print-out-a-heart-symbol#comment125266403_70858305), although I went ahead and did with the explanation.

Comment: yes I will. thank you so much!

Comment: While this is the correct (modern, reliable, portable, industry state-of-the-art, whatever) way to handle funny characters, being correct and satisfying a teacher are sometimes two mutually exclusive goals. The other answer shows an incorrect (antiquated, unreliable, non-portable, whatever) way to print the heart shape, but that one is more likely to achieve the second goal. Such is life.

Comment: I actually feel in this case the other answer is more useful to the OP.